# AMD graphics and slow graphcs issue

Tags: gpu-driver

I have an AMD 5500 XT card which seems to be sort of working but stuggling with higher graphics loads. This is a recent thing. I thought I would update the driver but ran into this issue which prevented loading after a recent system upgrade:

```
"Deleting module version: 15.201
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new fglrx-core-15.201 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.0-41-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.13.0-41-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/fglrx-core.0.cr
ash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/15.201/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fglrx-core (--configure):
 installed fglrx-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error
 exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx-core"
```

Any suggestions? Any advice about the really slow graphics at higher loads?

Comment: So you DID try to install an old driver, unsupported since 7-8 years ago... AMD graphics drivers since then are open-source, already included and installed according to the hardware - `radeon` for legacy hardware; `amdgou` for newer graphics -, NO user action required.

Comment: *amdgpu (correction to the above comment)

Comment: Except I am having GPU issues after the last upgrade - none before - so I have what options? Your comment is of no practical use. I need a solution.

Comment: Which "last upgrade"? Your other comment - *No, I tried to upgrade my firmware and GPU driver. Something obviously went wrong.* - suggests this was your doing so please, again, [edit] (one or the other, they're duplicates anyway) and describe EXACTLY what you did.

Comment: I had this question posted in two different ways. A helpful person made a suggestion for the firmware side of the issue which I applied, rebooted and everything seemed to be fine. I checked the purge worked and I checked the firmware had updated. The graphics issue seemed to have totally disappeared. Today I fired up my computer and same issue reappeared. When I move into a high load graphics environment - e.g. Zynga poker - the fans start to pump like mad and the graphics stutter and go very slow. Then I close down the app and everything reverts to calm. I am stumped.

Comment: FYI ChanganAuto: everything I had done has been undone and the issue predated my actions anyway. I think it has to be a Ubuntu bug of some kind from a recent update.

Comment: lshw -c video returns:  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe400000-fe47ffff memory:c0000-dffff

Comment: Def. some kind of bug. I spent most of last night deleting and re-installing the OS - issue persists.

Comment: Why do you keep installing `fglrx`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade issue: fglrx-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409461/upgrade-issue-fglrx-core)

Comment: I don't keep on installing fglrx. I just said, I replaced the entire OS. My understanding is that fglrx is redundant and is not included in current Ubuntu versions. On the suggestion of advice elsewhere I had tried a roll back to an earlier version of the driver because I thought it might help the problem - my bad, my error. I didn't repeat the mistake. I did the purge. In the session at the time it seemed to do the trick but when I re-logged in the problem reappeared. I checked, the purge has worked - no fglrx.

Comment: I've been doing some more digging. When my system has low graphic load programmes - e.g email, google - the CPU load is at 10% or so. When I open  high graphics load programme - e.g Zynga poker - the load shoots up to 675%+. This can't be normal. Does anyone one have a clue what is going on? I have tested the graphics card, it does not seem to be the issue and this is a recent problem, my system was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. amdgpu as it comes with 20.04 LTS - even upgraded - ain't cutting it. Download the driver from AMD for 20.04 LTS.