# Upgrade issue: fglrx-core

Tags: firmware

I tired to upgrade linux firmware and I get the following:

```
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.187.31 [125 MB]
Fetched 125 MB in 18s (7,027 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 194517 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.187.31_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.187.31) over (1.187.30) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.31) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
Setting up fglrx-core (2:15.201-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
Removing old fglrx-core-15.201 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 15.201
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new fglrx-core-15.201 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.0-41-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.13.0-41-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/fglrx-core.0.cr
ash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/15.201/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fglrx-core (--configure):
 installed fglrx-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error
 exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone have a solution please?

Comment: Have you at some point tried to install fglrx? If so why?

Comment: No, I tried to upgrade my firmware and GPU driver. Something obviously went wrong. And, FYI, I am not the first person to which this has happened. I have tried various suggested solutions but none work.

Comment: And how exactly did you try to "upgrade the GPU driver"? There lies the crux of the question. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Duplicate of [AMD graphics and slow graphcs issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409272/amd-graphics-and-slow-graphcs-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fglrx` is a legacy AMD GPU driver that is obsolete and can't be built against current Ubuntu kernels.

Remove it by

```
 sudo apt purge fglrx*
```

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I f***ed up somehow - I should have thought of that as a solution. It seems to have sorted the roadblock but not the underlying issue. I'll keep plugging away. Thanks again, much appreciated.